# Is it possible to replace the existing price on a website to a converted one with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

Past few days I have been trying to write some code for my Browser extension, and I have been stuck on converting the prices on the website.

I got so far to realise that I can technically get an array of prices trough `document.querySelectionAll('.price__blocks')`, but it doesn't let my code run that worked for me in a playground, because it gives out an error: `*VM8032:2 Uncaught TypeError: nodes[i].replace is not a function*`
at :2:38

### **Playground Code**

```
vals = ["80.00$", "50.00$", "70.00$", "69.99$"];
for (var i = 0; i < 4; ++i){
var priceNum = parseFloat(vals[i].replace(/$/g, ""))
priceNum = priceNum * 0.000020 + " BTC"
console.log(priceNum)
}
```

```js
vals = ["80.00$", "50.00$", "70.00$", "69.99$"];


for (var i = 0; i < 4; ++i){
  var priceNum = parseFloat(vals[i].replace(/$/g, ""))
  priceNum = priceNum * 0.000020 + " BTC"
  console.log(priceNum)
}
```

### **Actual Code**

```
var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('.price__block')
for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; ++i){
var priceNum = parseFloat(nodes[i].replace(/€/g, ""))
priceNum = priceNum * 0.000020 + " BTC"
nodes[i].innerHTML = priceNum;
}
```

```js
var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('.price__block')
for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; ++i){
    var priceNum = parseFloat(nodes[i].replace(/€/g, ""))
    priceNum = priceNum * 0.000020 + " BTC"
    nodes[i].innerHTML = priceNum;
  }
```

I'll attach screenshots for better understanding of my issue [images of VisualStudio Code and Playground](https://i.stack.imgur.com/muomL.png)

Comment: querySelectorAll returns a list of elements.  your test code is an array of strings.  strings have a replace method, elements do not.

Comment: You probably want to use `innerHTML` or `textContent` in `parseFloat(nodes[i].` ~ ie: `parseFloat(nodes[i].textContent.replace()`etc

Comment: Hi, responding to your suggestions, @ProfessorAbronsius textContent kinda works but for some reason in prints the price inside console not on the website, but for other example innerHTML changes all the prices, but to NaN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to ProfesorAbronsius, I was able to get a solution!

```js
var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('.price__block')

for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; ++i){
    var priceNum = parseFloat(nodes[i].textContent.replace(/€/g, ""))
    priceNum = priceNum * 0.000020 + " BTC"
    nodes[i].innerHTML = priceNum;
  }
```

Also ran into a new issue with this solution, but a minor one, it keeps multiplying the price every time I switch tabs, but I'm sure it's a quick solution!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

From your actual code, you're trying to call the replace function from an element, the replace function can only be called on a string.

To fix that, you might want to do:

```js
var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('.price__block')
for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; ++i){
    var priceNum = parseFloat(nodes[i].innerHTML.replace(/€/g, ""))
    priceNum = priceNum * 0.000020 + " BTC"
    nodes[i].innerHTML = priceNum;
  }
```

Comment: Hi, I tried running your code, and ran into something interesting, it does what it is supposed to do half-way I'd say. After running that code withing the browser console it does change the values to BTC accordingly, but for the website par it shows NaN instead of price. 

If I write console.log(nodes[...]) it gives me back the right value in console in BTC, but if I add the same line of code in my browser extension, it logs NaN into the console.

Comment: What do you mean browser extension?

Comment: I’m trying to develop a browser extension! ^^